# Probability of getting 14/15 unique cards out of 40 cards

Tags: probability

There are $40$ cards numbered $1$ to $40$. We pick $15$ cards with replacement. What is the probability that $15$ cards represent $15$ unique cards? What is the probability that $15$ cards represent $14$ unique cards?

I know for the first question, I'd be assuming that I would have to find the probability that the $15$ cards has less than $15$ unique cards? So I would be assuming that the answer would be
$ \displaystyle ~ \left[1 - {40 \choose 1} \cdot {15 \choose 15} / {40 \choose 15} \right]$

On the other hand, I do not know where to start for the next question.

Comment: No, even the first one is not correct. What is your reasoning behind ${3 \choose 1}{15 \choose 15}$? Can you please explain?

Comment: Next, where did ${50 \choose 15}$ come from in the denominator? I thought there were only $40$ cards? Also you have to pick with replacement, not without replacement.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo and fixed it to 40C1 and 15C15. My explanation for 40C1 is that there is there are 40 unique cards. What would I do in the case of replacement?

Comment: please think one card at a time. First pick can be any card. Doesn't matter. What is the probability for the next pick such that it is not same as the first card?

Comment: Would it be 1/49?

Comment: Wrong. How many cards do you have in total and how many of them are different from the first card?

Comment: Ohhh 39/40 I keep making typos thinking that it is 50 my bad

Comment: yes then for the third card to be different than the first two, the probability is $38/40$ and so on... so the probability should be $39 \cdot 38 \cdot... 26 / 40^{14}$

Comment: or rewrite it as $40! / (25! \cdot 40^{15})$

Comment: Can this be rewritten as 40P15 * 40^15?

Comment: Yes of course. You are choosing any $15$ numbers out of $40$ and then they can be picked in different orders.

Comment: Next time when you post a question, please do not just type an expression. Give your idea behind the expression. Also learn to use mathjax. Questions not using mathjax are not usually received well on the site.

Comment: Ohhh I see thank you! Keeping this is mind, how would this change when we can only have 14 unique cards? Would it be 40!/25! * 40^14

Comment: Ohhh I will use mathjax from now on after this response

Comment: For the second one, you need to choose $14$ numbers out of $40$, choose which number out of $14$ would repeat and then permutations are $15!/2!$. So it should be ${40 \choose 14}  {14 \choose 1}  \cdot 15! / 2!$. Denominator remains $40^{15}$

Comment: Where do you get the $2!$ from?

Comment: If there are $15$ letters and $2$ of them are same, how do you find their permutations?

Comment: Ohhh I understand that thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question $\frac{39\times 38\times ...\times 26}{40^{14}}$.

For the second (assuming exactly 14) $\frac{15}{2}\frac{39\times 38\times ...\times 27}{40^{13}}\frac{14}{40}$.  Explanation: $14$ different numbers (long fraction) with one number duplicated (last fraction) and the duplicate can be in any position (first fraction).